# How to setup a callback on a protected method using Moq?

Tags: moq

I cannot setup a callback on a protected method using Moq (v.4.2).

The code looks like following :

```
public abstract class AbstractClass
{
    protected abstract void OneProtectedMethod();
}

public class OneClass : AbstractClass
{
    protected override void OneProtectedMethod()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Hello");
    }

    public void DoMethod()
    {
        OneProtectedMethod();
    }
}

[Test]
public void should_call_protected_method()
{
    var mock = new Mock<OneClass>();

    mock.Protected().Setup("OneProtectedMethod").Callback(() => Console.WriteLine("Goodbye"));

    var o = new OneClass();

    o.DoMethod();

    mock.Protected().Verify("OneProtectedMethod", Times.Once());
}
```

Am I doing anything wrong here ?

Thanks.

Comment: The test does nothing, there is no relationship between the mock and the instance of the ```OneClass``` in the ```Act``` part. What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: I want to test if the method has been called on the object (and more, try to measure/calculate something, that's why the Callback). Is there any way to do that ?

Comment: Of course there is a way. See my answer with example. The problem in your test is that you do not have any relation between class under test and the mock. Both are independent. So when you call the ```DoMethod``` it can't have any influence on the mock. So you do setup the protected correctly but then the mock is not used. HTH

Comment: Indeed, your answer is very clear. Thanks.

Comment: Indeed, your answer is very clear. Thanks for that. However, my context is : I'm extending a class (AppenderSkeleton of log4net) and overriding the Append() method. And I want to test that the method does what I want. So, at the startup of the test, the logger is created (using the config) and does the logging (and calls my overrided method). At this point, I don't see how to catch the call (and the arguments) as I don't see where I can inject the class as your example. Can you show me how to do that? Thanks.

Comment: Aha log4net appender :). I would suggest you to create new question. This time describe the problem something like 'how to write unit test for my custom log4net appender'. Show your code you have so far and describe how your configuration of log4net looks like.

Comment: Thanks a lot @dee. I figured it out: I think I took my problem from a wrong point. In fact, I tried to mock my custom appender, but I don't need to. As I want to test it, I have to mock objects that it depends on (connection to database, service, etc.), and not itself.

Comment: Yes exactly, appender is your class under test for which you provide a real instance in the test. Mocks needs to be created only for dependencies of the cut.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your setup of protected method works well but it needs to be somehow related to class under test. Imagine some class like the following one. It has dependency to `OneClass` and this dependency can be mocked in the unit test.

```
public class Master
{
    // Master hes dependency on OneClass
    private readonly OneClass _dependency; 

    public Master(OneClass dependency)
    {
        _dependency = dependency;
    }

    public bool DoSomething()
    {
        // ... some code
        // dependency is used here
        _dependency.DoMethod();
        // ... some code

        return true;
    }
}
```

Then the test could look something like the following.

```
[TestMethod]
public void DoSomething_WhenCalled_ReturnsTrue()
{
    // Arrange
    var mock = new Mock<OneClass>();
    mock.Protected().Setup("OneProtectedMethod").Callback(() => Debug.WriteLine("Goodbye"));
    var master = new Master(mock.Object);

    // Act
    master.DoSomething();

    // Assert
    // ...
}
```

Here mocked version of `OneProtectedMethod` method will be used. So in the output only the text `Goodbye` will be written, the real implementation will be mocked. HTH.